# Access to the related QuoteLineItem in OpportunityLineItem Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem, quote

I'm looking for a way to access the `QuoteLineItem` from a `OpportunityLineItem` trigger when I sync a Quote with the Opportunity. How can I access the related `QuoteLineItem`? I looked at the "Custom Quote Sync" package on AppExchange, and the package doesn't seem to be working in my Salesforce.com instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my research, there's no "built-in" way to achieve this. However, I found an interesting thing helping me doing it: the IDs of your `QuoteLineItem` are in the exact same order as your `OpportunityLineItem`. Knowing this, you can match/sync data grammatically with two simple SOQL request (to obtain the two lists, ordered by ID) and match them one by one (first `OpportunityLineItem` with first `QuoteLineItem`...). You can implement this with triggers or with a button (depending on your business process).

I also suggest to add a lookup field linking the `QuoteLineItem` object to your `OpportunityLineItem` object. When you sync them, populate the field with the related quote item ID. Following this, you will be able to access `QuoteLineItem` information using formulas from your product.

Comment: I'll have to test this. I think at one point I thought they were non-deterministic because of some odd behavior I saw, but if this is true, it certainly is good news. Thanks for this tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple unless I am missing something here. 
If you are looking to access the Quote in a OpportunityLineItem trigger,

Get the Opportunity Id from your OpportunityLineItem.

```
Id oppId = olm.OpportunityId;
```

Then

```
SELECT Id FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId
```

**EDIT after question was modified:**
The above logic helps you do a match up at the Opp-Quote level. Syncing the actual QuoteLineItem with the OppLineItem will be more trickier.

You can get the list of line items from the respective quote and Opp. You will need to match them up based on the `PricebookEntryId`perhaps?

Comment: Nope, I want to associate each `OpportunityLineItem` with the related `QuoteLineItem`.

Comment: It seems that is not what your question is asking though. Would you be able to edit your question with what you want to do? If you just want to just get the quote ID you can do what Richard suggested or go one step further and put a WHERE isSyncing = TRUE at the end

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo =/!

Comment: Np jp. And to jnoel10's point you will need to check for the quote which was synced. I think you can also do something like when you have the opp object. 'Opportunity.SyncedQuote.Id'

Comment: @RichardN If you have multiple product with the same `PriceBookEntryId`, you cannot identify them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot identify the `OpportunityLineItem` associated with a `QuoteLineItem`. This is a pain point in our project, too. Our "solution" was to match the line items based on multiple criteria, such as PricebookEntryId, Quantity, UnitPrice, and Discount. In the event that two are identical, we simple update both of them and hope for the best. We're hoping that salesforce.com addresses this in the future.

Comment: You can check the answer I added, I found a solution in the past and forgot about this question. I think it's a dirty workaround, but it does match perfectly the two objects :)! Thanks for your answer!